# Query to show Tables and Table definition in Starcounter Database

Tags: starcounter

How can I get a list of table names and definitions by either SQL statement or code behind for the Starcounter DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metadata about created tables, their columns and indexes are stored in meta-data tables. Database classes are publicly exposed for corresponding meta-data tables.

Tables or types are described by `Starcounter.Metadata.RawView` and `Starcounter.Metadata.ClrClass` and both extends `Starctouner.Metadata.Table`. `ClrClass` contains description for loaded CLR classes only, while `RawView` describes all created tables. They include descriptions of user-defined classes/tables and metadata classes/tables.

For example, all loaded user-defined classes can be enumerated:

```
foreach(ClrClass c in Db.SQL<ClrClass>(
    "select c from Starcounter.Metadata.ClrClass c where Updatable = ?", true)) {
  Console.WriteLine(c.FullName);
}
```

Property `Updatable` of `Table` is `true` for user-defined tables and `false` for meta-data/system tables.

Properties or columns are described by `Starcounter.Metadata.Member` and its children. An example of enumerating all columns for all user-defined tables is:

```
foreach(Member m in Db.SQL<Member>(
    "select m from Column m, RawView v where m.Table = v and v.Updatable = ?",
    true)) {
  Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
}
```

Indexes are described by `Starcounter.Metadata.Index` and `Starcounter.Metadata.IndexedColumn`.

Currently it is one-to-one match between database classes and tables. However, this and metadata schema might change in future.